# Mysql Movie Database

Tags: mysql, movie

I'm creating a movie database and I think I have finished designing it, but my results are not coming back as I would like them too.  I only have 2 movies details in the database right now.  I'm trying to get it to stop displaying duplicate information.

Can you take a look and give feedback?

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
/*
 Navicat MySQL Data Transfer

 Source Server         : localhost
 Source Server Version : 50525
 Source Host           : localhost
 Source Database       : MovieDB

 Target Server Version : 50525
 File Encoding         : utf-8

 Date: 09/12/2013 22:06:21 PM
*/

SET NAMES utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `FORMAT`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `FORMAT`;
CREATE TABLE `FORMAT` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Formats` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `FORMAT_ID`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `FORMAT_ID`;
CREATE TABLE `FORMAT_ID` (
  `MovieID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FormatID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Num_Discs` int(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Locations` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MovieID`,`FormatID`),
  KEY `FormatID` (`FormatID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FORMAT_ID_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MovieID`) REFERENCES `MOVIE` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FORMAT_ID_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`FormatID`) REFERENCES `FORMAT` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `GENRE`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `GENRE`;
CREATE TABLE `GENRE` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Genres` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Descriptions` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `GENRE_ID`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `GENRE_ID`;
CREATE TABLE `GENRE_ID` (
  `MovieID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `GenreID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`MovieID`,`GenreID`),
  KEY `GenreID` (`GenreID`),
  CONSTRAINT `GENRE_ID_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`GenreID`) REFERENCES `GENRE` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `GENRE_ID_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MovieID`) REFERENCES `MOVIE` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `MOVIE`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MOVIE`;
CREATE TABLE `MOVIE` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Titles` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Alt_Titles` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Types` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Synopsis` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Images` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Num_Eps` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `Catagories` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `RENT`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `RENT`;
CREATE TABLE `RENT` (
  `MovieID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Rents` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Who` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Note` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MovieID`,`Rents`,`Who`),
  CONSTRAINT `RENT_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MovieID`) REFERENCES `MOVIE` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

sql:

```
select distinct Titles, Types, Num_Eps, Catagories, Duration, Formats, Num_Discs, Genres
from MOVIE, FORMAT, FORMAT_ID, GENRE, GENRE_ID
where MOVIE.ID=GENRE_ID.MovieID
AND GENRE_ID.GenreID=GENRE.ID
and MOVIE.ID=FORMAT_ID.MovieID
AND FORMAT_ID.FormatID=FORMAT.ID
order by Titles;
```

this is my results:

```
Titles,Types,Num_Eps,Catagories,Duration,Formats,Num_Discs,Genres
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,DVD,1,Mecha
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,DVD,1,Police
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,DVD,1,Psychological
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,DVD,1,Sci-Fi
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,DVD,1,Cyberpunk
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,Bluray,1,Mecha
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,Bluray,1,Police
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,Bluray,1,Psychological
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,Bluray,1,Sci-Fi
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,Bluray,1,Cyberpunk
Summer Wars,Movie,1,Anime,01:54:00,DVD,1,Comedy
Summer Wars,Movie,1,Anime,01:54:00,DVD,1,Sci-Fi
Summer Wars,Movie,1,Anime,01:54:00,HD,,Comedy
Summer Wars,Movie,1,Anime,01:54:00,HD,,Sci-Fi
```

Comment: What is the desired output? to have all the Genres in one column like Vulcronos suggests in his answer?

Comment: The desired output would be to have all genres for that particular movie listed once and for the formats to be listed once too.  Desired output example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody is probably looking at this thread any more, but I wanted to let future views and the people who helped me that I found what I was looking for in the question.

```
select DISTINCT m.Title, 
            group_concat(DISTINCT g.Genre) as Genres, 
            group_concat(DISTINCT f.Format) as Formats
from MOVIES m 
left join MOVIEGENRES mg on m.Code=mg.MovieCode
left join GENRES g on mg.GenCode=g.Code
left join MOVIEFORMATS mf on m.Code=mf.MovieCode
left join FORMATS f on mf.FormCode=f.Code
group by m.Code;
```

Answer (score 1):

A few points.  I would use full join syntax,

```
FROM MOVIE JOIN GENRE ON MOVIE.ID=GENRE_ID.MovieID
```

instead of the where clauses you have now.

Then you might want to try GROUP_CONCAT(expr) to concatenate your Genres into one line, ex. Mecha, Police, Psychological, etc...

Comment: so your saying do something like this?                                       select distinct Titles, Types, Num_Eps, Catagories, Duration, Genres
FROM MOVIE JOIN GENRE_ID ON MOVIE.ID=GENRE_ID.MovieID, GENRE
where GENRE_ID.GENREID=GENRE.ID
order by Titles;

Comment: Yes.  That looks like a start.  :)

Comment: Got the Genre to work just fine now, would I go about doing that the same way for formats?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Yes.  Any time you are joining two tables it is best to use the join on syntax. Makes it clear what you are doing.

Comment: I got that to work for formats, but is there any way to combine the two to get an output from both but only show one listing of each of the genres and one list of each of the formats at least?

Comment: @user2537388 You might want to edit your question to show what you are now getting, what you want, and what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  Thanks to Vulcronos I got genres and formats to list out right if I do them separate by using

Genre:

```
select distinct Titles, Types, Num_Eps, Catagories, Duration, Genres 
FROM MOVIE JOIN GENRE_ID ON MOVIE.ID=GENRE_ID.MovieID, GENRE 
where GENRE_ID.GENREID=GENRE.ID 
order by Titles;
```

format:

```
select distinct Titles, Types, Num_Eps, Catagories, Duration, Formats, Num_Discs, Locations 
FROM MOVIE JOIN FORMAT_ID ON MOVIE.ID=FORMAT_ID.MovieID, FORMAT 
where FORMAT_ID.FORMATID=FORMAT.ID 
order by Titles;
```

Is there any way to combine the two?

So I would get something like this:

```
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,DVD,1,Mecha
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,DVD,1,Police
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,DVD,1,Psychological
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,DVD,1,Sci-Fi
Ghost in the Shell,Movie,1,Anime,01:23:00,Bluray,1,Cyberpunk
Summer Wars,Movie,1,Anime,01:54:00,DVD,1,Comedy
Summer Wars,Movie,1,Anime,01:54:00,HD,,Sci-Fi
```

Where it would list the genres once and the formats once.  Of course with multiple genres the format will be repeated unless there is a way to fix that, but where it will at least show all the formats once along with genres once.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Is there any way to combine the two?" I know you already solved your issue and this is outdated, but for your future questions, don't ask another question in an answer - edit your original question instead or ask a new one if they aren't related. :)